# Azure Blob Storage - how to index (full text search) the contents inside the blob apart from Azure Cognitive search?

Tags: azure, full-text-search, azure-blob-storage

I have an existing application that stores all types of documents(currently ~9TB) with full text search enabled in sql server. Now planning to migrate to Azure blob storage/ Azure File Shares. I have explored azure cognitive services and there is a limit in storage. Is there any other successful approach to apply the full text search on the azure blob storage/ file shares?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What limit in storage?

Comment: Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-blob-storage-integration) to know more about Full text search over the Azure Blob Storage content.